# Hibernate CompositeUserType mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. Writing a CompositeUserType. When I run the code I am getting error.
property

mapping has wrong number of columns:
Please help me what am I missing?

My CompositeUserType goes as follows

```
 public  class EncryptedAsStringType implements CompositeUserType {
 @Override
 public String[] getPropertyNames() {
    return new String[] { "stockId", "stockCode", "stockName","stockDescription" };
}


@Override
public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
    //stockId, stockCode,stockName,modifiedDate
    return new Type[] { 
            Hibernate.INTEGER, Hibernate.STRING, Hibernate.STRING,Hibernate.STRING

    };
}
@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(final Object component, final int property)
        throws HibernateException {
    Object returnValue = null;
    final Stock auditData = (Stock) component;

    if (0 == property) {
        returnValue = auditData.getStockId();
    } else if (1 == property) {
        returnValue = auditData.getStockCode();
    } else if (2 == property) {
        returnValue = auditData.getStockName();
    }   return returnValue; 
}

@Override
public void setPropertyValue(final Object component, final int property,
        final Object setValue) throws HibernateException {
    final Stock auditData = (Stock) component;


}


 @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet,
            final String[] names,
            final SessionImplementor paramSessionImplementor, final Object paramObject)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        //owner here is of type TestUser or the actual owning Object
     Stock auditData = null;
        final Integer createdBy = resultSet.getInt(names[0]);
        //Deferred check after first read
        if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {
            auditData = new Stock();

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+resultSet.getInt(names[1]));
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+resultSet.getString(names[2]));
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+resultSet.getString(names[3]));
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+resultSet.getString(names[4]));
                 }
        return auditData;
    }


    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement preparedStatement,
            final Object value, final int property,
            final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (null == value) {


        } else {
            final Stock auditData = (Stock) value;
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+auditData.getStockCode());
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+auditData.getStockDescription());
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+auditData.getStockId());
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+auditData.getStatus());


        }
    }
```

My Domain class Stock has five attributes. (stockId,stockCode,StockName,Status , Stock 
Description)

I need to declare the field Stock description as Composite field Type.

```
 private Integer stockId;
private String stockCode;
private String stockName;
private String status;
private String stockDescription;

//Constructors  


@Column(name = "STOCK_CC", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
@Type(type="com.mycheck.EncryptedAsStringType")
@Columns(columns = { @Column(name="STOCK_ID"),
    @Column(name="STOCK_CODE"),
    @Column(name="STOCK_NAME")

   })
public String getStockDescription() {
    return stockDescription;
}
```

}

When I try to execute a insert for Stock. I am getting the error  Error creating bean with name

'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/config/../database/Hibernate.xml]:

Invocation of init method failed. nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:

property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.stock.model.Stock.stockDescription type:

com.mycheck.EncryptedAsStringType

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: you missed @Column(name="STOCK_DESCRIPTION") right?

Comment: STOCK_CC refers to the description. Do you see any issue there ?

Comment: @Column(name = "STOCK_CC", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)

Comment: The code works , when I declare a one property in  return new String[] { "stockDescription"} in the user Type class. If I add more than a column   return new String[] { "stockDescription","stockName"}; It says property mapping has wrong number of columns:

Comment: because you are trying to smash 3 column into 1 class field. Separate out your 3 columns into 3 fields. That will solve part of your problem

Comment: If I remove @Columns annotation. How The  getPropertyValue know the three columns I need to pass.

Comment: Have a look at the last example the way it calls http://javadata.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/hibernate-and-user-types.html

Answer (score 2):

One can extract the answer from the code samples and the comments to the original question, but to save everyone some reading, I've compiled a quick summary.

If you declare a `CompositeUserType` that maps a type to n columns, you have to declare n columns in `@Columns` besides the `@Type` annotation. Example:

```
public class EncryptedAsStringType implements CompositeUserType {
    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
       return new String[] { "stockId", "stockCode", "stockName","stockDescription" };
    }

    // ...
}
```

This `CompositeUserType` maps to 4 separate columns, therefore 4 separate `@Column` annotations have to be declared:

```
@Type(type="com.mycheck.EncryptedAsStringType")
@Columns(columns = {
    @Column(name="STOCK_ID"),
    @Column(name="STOCK_CODE"),
    @Column(name="STOCK_NAME"),
    @Column(name="STOCK_DESCRIPTION")
})
public String getStockDescription() {
    return stockDescription;
}
```

That's it and Hibernate is happy.

Comment: Custom NamingStrategy should be able to define unique column names for CompositeUserType's with 2 columns or more: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11812