# Implementing Custom hibernate type

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, custom-type

I am  trying to implement hibernate mapping to sample schema (Order Entry) provided by Oracle default installation
The orderentry schema has several table one of them is Customer table which is having few Columns as customTyped columns for example
the custom type is created with the following statement ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CUST_ADDRESS_TYP"  AS OBJECT
( street_address     VARCHAR2(40)
, postal_code        VARCHAR2(10)
, city               VARCHAR2(30)
, state_province     VARCHAR2(10)
, country_id         CHAR(2)
);
```

and the customer table is created with the below statement

```
CREATE TABLE OE.CUSTOMERS 
( 
 CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER (6)  NOT NULL , 
 CUST_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE) 
 CONSTRAINT CUST_FNAME_NN NOT NULL , 
 CUST_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE) 
 CONSTRAINT CUST_LNAME_NN NOT NULL , 
 CUST_ADDRESS OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP , 
 )
```

I came to know that we need to implement the `UserType` interface from [here](http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2011/09/creating-hibernate-custom-type-1.html) but when I try to retrieve it was giving the error

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.dto.oe.Customers.cust_addressData type: com.dto.oe.CustAddressType
            at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:497)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
at com.test.connection.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:82)
at com.test.connection.HibernateUtil.getCustomer(HibernateUtil.java:70)
at com.test.connection.HibernateUtil.main(HibernateUtil.java:18)
```

Wheras my `Customtype` object pojo class is `Cust_addressData` and the class which implemented usertype interface is `CustAddressType`

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Types;

    import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
    import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
    import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

    public class CustAddressType implements UserType {
    /**
     * Returns the object from the 2 level cache
     */
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    /**
     * Used to create Snapshots of the object
     */
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        final Cust_addressData recievedParam = (Cust_addressData) value;
        final Cust_addressData addressData = new Cust_addressData(recievedParam);
        return addressData;
    }

    /**
     * method called when Hibernate puts the data in a second level cache. The
     * data is stored in a serializable form
     */
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object value)
            throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o1, final Object o2)
            throws HibernateException {
        boolean isEqual = false;
        if (o1 == o2) {
            isEqual = true;
        }
        if (null == o1 || null == o2) {
            isEqual = false;
        } else {
            isEqual = o1.equals(o2);
        }
        return isEqual;
        // for this to work correctly the equals()
        // method must be implemented correctly by Cust_addressData class
    }

    public int hashCode(final Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
        return arg0.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet, final String[] names,
            SessionImplementor sessionImp, final Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        // owner here is class from where the call to retrieve data was made.
        // In this case the Test class

        Cust_addressData addresssData = new Cust_addressData();
        // Order of columns is given by sqlTypes() method
        if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {


            final String street_address = resultSet.getString(names[0]);
            final String postal_code = resultSet.getString(names[1]);
            final String city = resultSet.getString(names[2]);
            final String state_province = resultSet.getString(names[3]);
            final String country_id = resultSet.getString(names[4]);

            addresssData.setCity(city);
            addresssData.setCountry_id(country_id);
            addresssData.setPostal_code(postal_code);
            addresssData.setState_province(state_province);
            addresssData.setStreet_address(street_address);
            System.out.println("street_address "+street_address +"  names  "+names[0]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("resultSet is null in CustAddressType");
        }
        return addresssData;
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object value, final int index,
            SessionImplementor arg3) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (null == value) {
            statement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
            statement.setNull(index + 1, Types.VARCHAR);
            statement.setNull(index + 2, Types.VARCHAR);
            statement.setNull(index + 3,Types.VARCHAR);
            statement.setNull(index + 4,Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            Cust_addressData addressData = (Cust_addressData) value;

            if (null != addressData.getStreet_address()) {
                String  street_address = new String(addressData.getStreet_address());
                statement.setString(index , street_address);
            } else {
                statement.setNull(index , Types.VARCHAR);
            }

            if (null != addressData.getPostal_code()) {
                 String  postal_Code = new String(addressData.getPostal_code());
                 statement.setString(index+1 , postal_Code);
            } else {
                statement.setNull(index +1, Types.VARCHAR);
            }

            if (null != addressData.getCity()) {
             String  city = new String(addressData.getCity());
                statement.setString(index+2 , city);
           } else {
               statement.setNull(index +2, Types.VARCHAR);
           }

            if (null != addressData.getState_province()) {
             String  postal_Code = new String(addressData.getState_province());
                statement.setString(index+3 , postal_Code);
           } else {
               statement.setNull(index +3, Types.VARCHAR);
           }


            if (null != addressData.getCountry_id()) {
             String  postal_Code = new String(addressData.getCountry_id());
                statement.setString(index+4 , postal_Code);
           } else {
               statement.setNull(index +4, Types.VARCHAR);
           }

        }

    }

    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target,
            final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(original);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Cust_addressData.class;
    }

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
                Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR };
    }
}
```

```
     import java.io.Serializable;
     import javax.persistence.Column;
     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.Table;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Entity
    @Table(name="CUST_ADDRESS_TYP")
    public class Cust_addressData implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "street_address")
    private String street_address;
    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postal_code;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "state_province")
    private String state_province;
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private String country_id;

    public Cust_addressData() {
    }

    public Cust_addressData(Cust_addressData other) {
        this.setCity(other.getCity());
        this.setCountry_id(other.getCountry_id());
        this.setPostal_code(other.getPostal_code());
        this.setStreet_address(other.getStreet_address());
        this.setState_province(other.getState_province());

    }

    public String getStreet_address() {
        return street_address;
    }

    public void setStreet_address(String street_address) {
        this.street_address = street_address;
    }

    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState_province() {
        return state_province;
    }

    public void setState_province(String state_province) {
        this.state_province = state_province;
    }

    public String getCountry_id() {
        return country_id;
    }

    public void setCountry_id(String country_id) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        boolean isEqual = false;
        if (obj instanceof Cust_addressData) {
            Cust_addressData addressData = (Cust_addressData) obj;

            isEqual = addressData.getCity().equals(this.getCity())
                    && addressData.getState_province().equals(this.getState_province())
                    && addressData.getCountry_id().equals(this.getCountry_id())
                    && addressData.getPostal_code().equals(this.getPostal_code())
                    && addressData.getStreet_address().equals(this.getStreet_address())
                    ;
        }
        return isEqual;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = this.getCountry_id().hashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + this.getPostal_code().hashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + this.getStreet_address().hashCode();
        hash = hash * 13 + this.getState_province().hashCode();
        hash = hash * 14 + this.getCity().hashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "[ " + this.getClass() + " { city : " + city
                + ", street_address: " + street_address + ", postal_code: "
                + postal_code + ", state_province: " + state_province + ""
                        + ",country_id :"+country_id+"}]";
    }
}
```

Full sources:

- [CustAddressType](https://github.com/devikiran/OrderEntry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dto/oe/CustAddressType.java)
- [Cust_addressData](https://github.com/devikiran/OrderEntry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dto/oe/Cust_addressData.java)
- [Customers](https://github.com/devikiran/OrderEntry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dto/oe/Customers.java)

One more observation is the sqlTypes method which is in CustAddressType class

```
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
        Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR };
}
```

is the one which is returning the number of columns if i make it to return only one column i'm getting the column value as null.

not sure exactly what is goin wrong,Any suggestion where I am doing wrong or any clue will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942960/hibernate-compositeusertype-mapping-has-wrong-number-of-columns

Comment: I have implemented UserType Interface not the CompositeUserType ..and moreover i have tried with CompositeUserType  also but still the issue remains the same.

Comment: Have you tried following [this blog post](http://dinukaroshan.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/hibernate-and-oracle-user-defined-types.html) as closely as possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using STRUCT class in my `CustAddressType` class has resolved the issue the source code the `CustAddressType` class is as follows.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.sql.Types;

import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class CustAddressType implements UserType {
    private static final int SQL_TYPE = Types.STRUCT;
    private static final String OBJECT_TYPE = "CUST_ADDRESS_TYP";
    /**
     * Returns the object from the 2 level cache
     */
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException {
    return cached;
}

/**
 * Used to create Snapshots of the object
 */
public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Cust_addressData recievedParam = (Cust_addressData) value;
    final Cust_addressData addressData = new Cust_addressData(recievedParam);

    return addressData;
}

/**
 * method called when Hibernate puts the data in a second level cache. The
 * data is stored in a serializable form
 */
public Serializable disassemble(final Object value)
        throws HibernateException {
    return (Serializable) value;
}

public boolean equals(final Object o1, final Object o2)
        throws HibernateException {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    if (o1 == o2) {
        isEqual = true;
    }
    if (null == o1 || null == o2) {
        isEqual = false;
    } else {
        isEqual = o1.equals(o2);
    }
    return isEqual;
    // for this to work correctly the equals()
    // method must be implemented correctly by Cust_addressData class
}

public int hashCode(final Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return arg0.hashCode();
}

public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet, final String[] names,
        SessionImplementor sessionImp, final Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    // owner here is class from where the call to retrieve data was made.
    // In this case the Test class

    final Cust_addressData addresssData = new Cust_addressData();

    final Struct struct = (Struct) resultSet.getObject(names[0]);

    if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    addresssData.setCity((String)struct.getAttributes()[0]);
    addresssData.setCountry_id((String)struct.getAttributes()[1]);
    addresssData.setPostal_code((String)struct.getAttributes()[2]);
    addresssData.setState_province((String)struct.getAttributes()[3]);
    addresssData.setStreet_address((String)struct.getAttributes()[4]);

    return addresssData;
}

public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object value, final int index,
        SessionImplementor arg3) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
        statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPE, OBJECT_TYPE);
    } 
    else {
        final Cust_addressData addresssData = (Cust_addressData) value;
        final Object[] values = new Object[] { addresssData.getCity(),addresssData.getCountry_id(), addresssData.getPostal_code(),
                addresssData.getState_province(),addresssData.getStreet_address() };
        final Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
        final STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(StructDescriptor.createDescriptor( OBJECT_TYPE,connection), connection, values);
        statement.setObject(index, struct, SQL_TYPE);
    }
}

public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target,
        final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return this.deepCopy(original);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Class returnedClass() {
    return Cust_addressData.class;
}

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] {SQL_TYPE};
}
}
```

Thanks to **@SteveChambers** for pointing it out,

Answer (score 0):

my friend where are the hibernate Annotations ? you have to clear define your each field with the name including your table name ...

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUST_ADDRESS_TYP")
public class Cust_addressData implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Column(name ="column_name")
private String street_address;
  @Column(name ="column_name")
private String postal_code;
  @Column(name ="column_name")
private String city;
  @Column(name ="column_name")
private String state_province;
  @Column(name ="column_name")
private String country_id;

public Cust_addressData() {
}

public Cust_addressData(Cust_addressData other) {
    this.setCity(other.getCity());
    this.setCountry_id(other.getCountry_id());
    this.setPostal_code(other.getPostal_code());
    this.setStreet_address(other.getStreet_address());
    this.setState_province(other.getState_province());

}

public String getStreet_address() {
    return street_address;
}

public void setStreet_address(String street_address) {
    this.street_address = street_address;
}

public String getPostal_code() {
    return postal_code;
}

public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
    this.postal_code = postal_code;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState_province() {
    return state_province;
}

public void setState_province(String state_province) {
    this.state_province = state_province;
}

public String getCountry_id() {
    return country_id;
}

public void setCountry_id(String country_id) {
    this.country_id = country_id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    boolean isEqual = false;
    if (obj instanceof Cust_addressData) {
        Cust_addressData addressData = (Cust_addressData) obj;

        isEqual = addressData.getCity().equals(this.getCity())
                && addressData.getState_province().equals(this.getState_province())
                && addressData.getCountry_id().equals(this.getCountry_id())
                && addressData.getPostal_code().equals(this.getPostal_code())
                && addressData.getStreet_address().equals(this.getStreet_address())
                ;
    }
    return isEqual;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = this.getCountry_id().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 17 + this.getPostal_code().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + this.getStreet_address().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 13 + this.getState_province().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 14 + this.getCity().hashCode();
    return hash;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "[ " + this.getClass() + " { city : " + city
            + ", street_address: " + street_address + ", postal_code: "
            + postal_code + ", state_province: " + state_province + ""
                    + ",country_id :"+country_id+"}]";
}
```

try to put the correct name for each column on the top of each variable and dont make it public .. good luck

Comment: i have tried implementing your changes still the issue remains same...by looking at the stack trace any idea what went wrong?

Comment: could you please place here the result of stack trace here ?

Comment: are you sure you put the right column names the place where i mentioned "column_name" ?  @Column(name ="column_name")  after doing it show me the console result i can help you further ..

Comment: u don't have ID column and primary key coulmn inside your  table in the DB, but for Hibernate we need at least one ID primary key,  so define the primary key and then declare that filed is id field like this                                          @id                                                                                                 private  long/string  primary key

Comment: "CUST_ADDRESS_TYP" its not a table it is a type if you can see my post initial line i have kept the creation statement ..so it cant have somehtinglike PrimaryKey..and after adding the column_name also there was no change in the console error.its the same one