# Spring Boot Hibernate mapping set of enums to boolean columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, nhibernate-mapping, compositeusertype

I have a Form enitity in Spring Boot application:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Form {
    @Id
    private String caseId;
    private String leadingUnit;
    private Set<Addiction> currentAddictions;
}
```

Addiction is an enum:

```
public enum Addiction {
  Alcohol, Nicotine, Drugs
}
```

And I would like to map the whole form to one table in database. With the following columns:
caseId, leadingUnit, currentAddictionsAlcohol, currentAddictionsNicotine and currentAddictionsDrugs.
I would like the currentAddictions* columns to bo boolean indicating only if the current addiction is present in the set. I was looking at custom UserTypes but I have no idea how to do it. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: which database are you using? which datatype in the database you want to use for **currentAddictions**

Comment: I am using postgresql and I want to use bit datatype or anything else that represents boolean, even integers with 0 and 1 will do.

Comment: ok, 1 caseid can have multiple addictions, so can you save multiple values in one column, I would suggest create one more table caseAddiction with one to many relationship

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't feel right (map a set to boolean columns). But here are a few options. Both options I can think require the the individual booleans to be mapped in the entity class. I want to be super clear: the correct way to map this is to have a table of addictions, and then link the tables. If later you want to add an extra addiction, this just becomes inserting a new row rather than changing the structure of the database.

- Change the interface of your class to have a get/set for each boolean value, each `set` method then adds or remove the value from the `Set` that is not persisted. The `Set` can only be modified from the `set` boolean methods. And you probably need to use a @PostLoad lifecycle method to populate the set after loading an entity.
- Basically the opposite: You only expose the `Set` with a couple of helper methods `addAddiction(Addiction)` and `removeAddiction(Addiction)`. These methods internally update boolean values that are not exposed in any way. So from the interface of the class, you only have a `Set`.

Last option, but it's a bit of an advanced approach (so more voodoo), is to use a `CompositeUserType`. You can find some examples of how to create this class in here too: [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132548/hibernate-compositeusertype-that-is-comparible-in-jpa-ql-or-hql-query), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942960/hibernate-compositeusertype-mapping-has-wrong-number-of-columns).

My recommendation would be to stay away from the CustomUserType as things might be really complicated if, for example, you want to query all the rows with `addiction = Alcohol`. And please do consider mapping the addictions to their own table. Your future self (or future maintainers) will appreciate it.

Comment: This table wil be used only for neural networks. The data will be saved and edited in another table. The problem is the I want to have a generic solution for multiply enums in this class, do you have an idea for it?

Comment: I would still use a different table for the `Addictions`. This is just my gut feeling, but I think that the other options I mentioned will be an exchange of `faster development now` for `maintenance nightmare later`. If this is **truly a throwaway** project, you could use a custom `CompositeUserType`, but you'll need to write quite a bit of reflection to map the columns automatically (as you'll need to map the enums to columns automatically). So in the end it might be better to use a different approach from the start.